# Finding sub-regions in an STL file for Finite Element

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, mesh

I use an external software (Amira) to segment X-ray tomography images and then create a surface mesh which I can then import into Mathematica as an STL file. This file has two enclosed regions, separated by a common boundary. I would like to be able to assign different material properties to the two regions for mechanical finite element simulations. How can this be done efficiently?

I guess as long as I know the coordinates of a point that lies within each region then I should be able to define region markers that could help me here.

As a minimum working example I have created the following mesh, which consists of a rectangular prism of dimensions 1 x 1 x 2, which is separated into 2 cubic regions of equal size (1x 1x 1).

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 2.0}, {1.0, 0.0,2.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 2.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 2.0}},"BoundaryElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8}, {3, 8, 7}, {4,1, 5}, {4, 5, 8}, {8, 5, 6}, {8, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 10}, {5, 10, 9}, {6, 7, 11}, {6, 11, 10}, {7, 8, 12}, {7, 12, 11}, {8, 5,9}, {8, 9, 12}, {12, 9, 10}, {12, 10, 11}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22}]}]
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"], bmesh["Wireframe"[ "MeshElement" -> "PointElements", "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Blue]],  bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]
```

[image: Mesh]

Following the documentation for [ToElementMesh](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) I naively thought that we could just add region markers.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 10}, {{0.5, 0.5, 1.5}, 20}},  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
mesh["Wireframe"[
"MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[FaceForm[Green]],Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}]]
```

[image: meshedwithregions]

Any hint as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The definition of `bmesh` contains a triangelelement of all points `TriangleElement[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
  20, 21, 22}]`, is this intended?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, it contains a list of markers; what you quote is not complete.

Comment: @user21 Thanks. I only took the last element of `TriangleElement[{...,{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,    20, 21, 22}}]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, please look again, the syntax is different from what you claim it to be.

Comment: @user21 I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at the boundary elements; you'd need to look at the mesh elements.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 10}, {{0.5, 0.5, 1.5}, 20}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
mesh["MeshElementMarkerUnion"]
(* {10, 20} *)

mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
  "MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[Opacity[0.75], FaceForm[Green]], 
    Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, Thanks! Should this question be closed as it seems like this is a mistake related to me using the wrong commands for mesh visualisation?

Comment: @Dunlop, I'd leave that up to you. What would be useful for me to know, is how I could improve the documentation in such a way that you would have prevented this misunderstanding. If you have a suggestion, let me know.

Comment: Ok, I will go again to the documentation and see what would have helped me here. I have to say the extended documentation on FE is really good and I am learning a lot.

Comment: To be honest it was in the documentation stating that boundary meshes are visualized in 3D. I guess what I wasn't sure about doing was working out whether the region assignment for the meshes had worked or not, and that got me confused with the visualisation. What could help for the future is something in the documentation that gives a 3D example of meshes where regions with different properties can be created.

Comment: @Dunlop, OK, is this something you would have found useful: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html#954199870? I have added links from the ElementMeshGeneration and ElementMeshVisualization tutorials to this section.

Comment: This is a good idea. What is unclear to me however is when the OpenCascadeLink should be used, and when we rely on internal Mathematica functionality.

Comment: @Dunlop, in 3D basically use/look at OpenCascade when you can not get a decent solution otherwise.